# How to get OneDrive icon back in task bar?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I setup a new Windows 10 PC where I installed OneDrive from its official website and then signed in with my university account. But OneDrive was also previously installed on Windows, and it was already signed in with my outlook account email that is also my user account. So, I got 2 OneDrive icons in the task bar.

And then, both icons vanished when I paused OneDrive for 2 hours. Since then I have restarted Windows, reset OneDrive, uninstalled and re-installed OneDrive, but the icons are not seen again. But I can still see the OneDrive folder in the Windows Explorer (not syncing though). I have tried different methods to get the icons back, some of them are explained [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/restore-missing-onedrive-icon-taskbar-windows10/)

Is Windows 10 blocking OneDrive? Is the OneDrive icon not appearing because I paused it? What can I do to start syncing again?

### EDIT

OneDrive shows up in the Apps list in Settings:

[image]

Clicking OneDrive from the Start menu does not open anything:

[image]

### EDIT 2

Following the advice in comments, I tried the following. The first command runs but the second throws an error:

[image]

Comment: Does One Drive show up in Windows 10 Settings, Apps?  If so look down the Alphabet list of Apps (Start, look down the left side) for One Note and see if you can start it there.

Comment: @John Yes, it appears in the Settings but clicking on it in Start menu does not do anything.

Comment: Try the following - no guarantee.   Open an Admin Command Prompt.  (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup   (2) dism.exe  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  (3) SFC /SCANNOW  .   Restart when done and check.

Comment: I tried it. The second command throws an error. Thank you though.

Comment: OK, thanks for that update.  What you need to do is a Repair Install.  Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything. 

You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to a clean install.

Comment: The second command needed capital letters for Cleanup and Restore. I ran it successfully, ran SFC /SCANNOW, and then restarted. Nothing changed. I am now trying the repair install.

Comment: @John UPDATE: I did the repair install, but OneDrive still does not show up in the taskbar. It does not open when I find it from the Start menu.

Comment: When Repair Install fails in this kind of issue, the reason is usually a damaged Windows User Profile.  The only practical cure in this case is to backup all your data, documents, and Email and then do a fresh install of Windows and restore applications and documents/email.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @John. I did a fresh install and OneDrive is working now.

Comment: I will post an answer and hopefully you will acknowledge that. It may help others as well, so best as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem backgroun**d:  One Drive not working (accessible).

DISM / SFC failed to help.
Windows 10 Repair Install failed to help.

**Solution:**

When Repair Install fails in this kind of issue, the reason is usually a damaged Windows User Profile.

The only practical cure in this case is to backup all your data, documents, and Email and then do a fresh install of Windows and restore applications and documents/email.

This will almost always solve the problem.